# How do I change the size of the <figure> area?

Tags: css

I have a figure tag for my shopping cart icon, which sits beside the header navigation. The png img inside is the perfect size, and fills the height of the figure tag. But for some reason, the figure tag is too long. I've tried resizing the figure tag width and the image width, but nothing will make it smaller or erase that empty space which is covering my final menu option. I didn't have or notice this problem earlier, but I made some necessary changes to the CSS and since then, I've noticed this issue. No matter what I change, nothing seems to alter the figure size. [It spans across so I cannot hover over the 'help' option].

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header-split">
                <a class="home" href="#">Lu Steven</a>
                <div class="menu-cart">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="overall-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
                            <li><span>|</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                            <li><span>|</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
                            <li><span>|</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#">exhibitions</a></li>
                            <li><span>|</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                            <li><span>|</span></li>
                            <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="/images/cart.png"></img>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Header */

header ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 150%;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-left: -35%;
}

header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
}

header a:hover{
    color: #9ec8f0; 
}

.header-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.header-split{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.home{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu-cart{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Cart */

figure{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: right;
}

header img{
    height: auto;
    width: 35%;
}

header img:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there there is a small error in your code the img is a self closing tag you don't need to close it like this `</img>` it should be something like this

```
<img src="" alt=""/>
```

correct this error and your problem might get solved

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem, but thank you for catching that error anyway!

Comment: Hi i checked your problem again and it seems there is a margin coming on figure tag try to set the margin to 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).